# URL rewrites for asp.net ecommerce site with LONG url's

Tags: asp.net, url, url-rewriting

I have a ecommerce site that started in php and has been migrated to an asp.net.

I find that unless I am extremely specific with my designer, the changes I want to happen don't.

One thing that is driving me NUTS is the very long urls.. say for example, a category page from the following hierarchy:
Maternity and Nursing Clothing
    - Maternity Pants & Jeans
         - Maternity Jeans
returns a URL of www.exampledomain.com/store/category/maternity%20and%20nursing%20clothing/maternity%20pants%20&%20jeans/maternity%20jeans.aspx! Come on!

Designer is working on replacing spaces with hyphens... whilst he's there, is there a way I can show him to make these url's more user friendly? Is there a way to skip everything but the final product category? So, www.exampledomain.com/maternity-jeans.aspx?

To make it easier should I remove the hierarchy and just have the final category straight from the home page? I didn't want to do this as there are quite a lot of subcategories, nothing deeper than this example.

Any advice would be warmly received. As i said, if I don't say to my designer, this is what I want and this is how I think you do it I get brushed off - due to a couple of reasons I am stuck with them for the moment.

Comment: Oh, and should I avoid "&" in url's? Can my rewrites be set up to ignore th "&" or "and" for me? My previous php site could.

Answer (score 0):

I would personally go with a URL structure that involves the least amount of characters, for example:

http://www.example.com/maternity-jeans

Not only is this clean, it is better for SEO because there are less useless words like "store" and "category". It is also slightly better for security because it doesn't make it obvious that you're site is built on ASP.NET.

To achieve this URL structure, I would normally opt for using [Helicon ISAPI rewrite](http://www.helicontech.com/isapi_rewrite/), if you're on a dedicated server, you might be able to get away with the free version, otherwise there's a fee of $99.

Another alternative would be to use IIS Url rewrites, you'll need to be running IIS 7 and above to use these.

I'm assuming you have a single category page that all categories load from? For the example below, I'll refer to it as "category.aspx".

These 2 rules below will catch the name of the category and pass it through as a query string parameter of your "category.aspx" page which you can then use to query the database and render the page.

Helicon ISAPI:

```
RewriteRule ^/(.*)$            /category.aspx?name=$1 [L]
```

IIS Url rewrite:

```
<rule name="Category" stopProcessing="true">
    <match url="(.*)" />
    <action type="Rewrite" url="category.aspx?name={R:1}" />
</rule>
```

Although the above URL structure would be my preference, you might have to take into consideration the URLs of the other pages on your site. The above rules will take any URL and assume it's a category, obviously not all URLs will be categories.

In this case you have a couple of options, you could either include a unique word or character to identify that it's a category, e.g:

http://www.example.com/c/maternity-jeans

This would change your rewrites:

Helicon ISAPI:

```
RewriteRule ^/c/(.*)$            /category.aspx?name=$1 [L]
```

IIS Url rewrite:

```
<rule name="Category" stopProcessing="true">
    <match url="c/(.*)" />
    <action type="Rewrite" url="category.aspx?name={R:1}" />
</rule>
```

Or, you could run every page through a script on your site which would work out what type of page you're viewing based on the URL and then render the appropriate content.

It does greatly depend how your site works at the moment and if you're prepared to make changes.